# graphdb inference rules - multiple constraint on a variable

Tags: inference, graphdb

Is it possible to have a single inf. rule with more than one constraints on a variable. For example is it possible to extend the following rule

```
  a b c [Constraint b != <rdf:type>]
  b <rdfs:domain> d
------------------------------------
  a <rdf:type> d
```

like that (tried but the rule is not activated)

```
  a b c [Constraint b != <rdf:type>,  b != <rdfs:label>]
  b <rdfs:domain> d
------------------------------------
  a <rdf:type> d
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the latest GraphDB [documentation](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/reasoning.html#rules) this is a valid rule syntax. Both constraints are executed with AND, so the rule will not work for `rdf:type` and `rdfs:label` values only. Here is the full example:

```
Prefices
{
    rdf : http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#
    rdfs : http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#
}

Axioms
{
}

Rules
{
    Id: test

    a b c [Constraint b != <rdf:type>,  b != <rdfs:label>]
    b <rdfs:domain> d
    ------------------------------------
    a <rdf:type> d

}
```

After inserting the sample file, you will get implicit result only for `<urn:a1>`:

```
<urn:a1> <urn:b1> <urn:c1> .
<urn:b1> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#domain> <urn:d1> .
<urn:a2> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> <urn:c2> .
<urn:b2> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#domain> <urn:d2> .
```

Comment: Thanks Vassil. Are there any other operators like equal ? is it possible to apply OR logic in the execution?